# error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token

Tags: c, gcc, token

I get this error in a C header file in this line :

```
char * getFechaHora(time_t & tiempoPuro);
```

In a C source code file i am including the header file and giving the function an implementation

```
char * getFechaHora(time_t &tiempoPuro){...}
```

also in my header file i am including correctly the "time.h" library.

Comment: Lemme state this once again: `C/C++` is not a language.

Comment: C is pass by value only. If you want to change the value of a variable passed to a function you must pass a pointer to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C, if char * getFechaHora, this is your function and the two (time_t & tiempoPuro) are arguments you should declare the function as:

```
char * getFechaHora(*type* time_t, *type* tiempoPuro);
```

else if the second is a variable, declare as

```
char * getFechaHora(time_t *tiempoPuro);
```

Answer (score 24):

```
char * getFechaHora(time_t & tiempoPuro);
```

This is not C. C has no reference (`&`).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your use of the `&` symbol.  Passing by reference in that way is not supported in C.  To accomplish this in C, you need to pass in a pointer to the variable like so:

```
    char * getFechaHora(time_t * tiempoPuro);
```

Technically, you are still passing by value (passing the value of the pointer), but it will accomplish the same thing (modifying the value pointed to by the `tiempoPuro` variable local to the `getFechaHora` function will change the value of the variable local to the function it was called from).

Reference:  [Pass by Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr233.htm)