# error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token

Tags: c, gcc, token

```
    void cargarProducto (Producto &p)
{
    printf("\nIngrese el c¢diqo: ");
    scanf("%d", &p.codigo);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nIngrese la descripci¢n: ");
    int i;
    printf("\nIngrese 1 si es importado");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if(i == 1)
    {
        p.discriminante = IMPORTADO;
    }
    else
    {
        p.discriminante = LOCAL;
    }
    if(p.discriminante == IMPORTADO)
    {
        printf ("\nIngrese al origen:");
        scanf("%c", &p.origen);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\nIngrese el telefono");
        scanf ("%d", &p.impoExpo.telefono);
    }
}
```

In the line void cargarProducto (Producto &p) throws the following error: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token

```
void copiar (Producto &destino, Producto origen)
{
    destino.codigo=origen.codigo;
    destino.descripcion=origen.descripcion;
    destino.unidadMedida=origen.unidadMedida;
    destino.precio=origen.precio;
    destino.discriminante.origen.discriminante;
    if (destino.discriminante ==IMPORTADO)
    {
        destino.impoExpo.origen=origen.impoExpo.origen;
    }
    else
    {
        impoExpo.telefono=origen.impoExpo.telefono;
    }
}
```

The same in the line void copiar (Producto &destino, Producto origen)

Comment: That's not valid C. Maybe you were trying to write a C++ program?

Comment: @Zeta Good point.  Missed that `&`.

Comment: Unrelated, but are you sure you want to encode the origing with a single character? There are more countries in the world than printable ASCII characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904091/error-expected-or-before-token)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your intention is to have `copiar` directly modify `destino`, you must pass the address of `destino`.  Passing by reference doesn't exist in C.

```
void copiar (Producto * const destino, const Producto * const origen)
{
    destino->codigo = origen->codigo;
    destino->descripcion = origen->descripcion;
    destino->unidadMedida = origen->unidadMedida;
    destino->precio = origen->precio;
    destino->discriminante = origen->discriminante;

    if(destino->discriminante == IMPORTADO)
        destino->impoExpo.origen = origen->impoExpo.origen;
    else
        impoExpo->telefono = origen->impoExpo.telefono;
}
```

It's better to pass structures by address, even if you don't plan on modifying their contents.  This is because structures may be large and you don't want to put them on the stack if not needed.  Declare structures `const` where needed.  In the above code, the address of `destino` is constant, but not the data; for `origen`, both the address and data are constant.

Answer (score 4):

You're apparently writing a C++ program, not a C program. Use the correct compiler in this case (`g++`) and one of correct extensions like `.cc`, `.cpp`, `.cxx`...).

Comment: Given the use of C standard I/O rather than C++, it is not clear whether Alejandro knows whether he is writing C or C++ (though the tags suggest C rather than C++) — but the compiler is a C compiler and the `&` used like that is C++ code, so the two are not going to be happy until the code is changed to C or the compiler is changed to C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah, the structure of his program suggests that he wants plain C, but saw the reference syntax from C++ and thought that it might be C as well. For the C variant there's already a nice answer, while in C++ one doesn't really need to write a copy function if the members/logic are/is that simple (although that if/else doesn't make sense to me at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

The code presented in the question did not work since it is a "mix" of C with C ++. Here I present the correct code implemented in C.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    typedef enum {IMPORTED, LOCAL} type;

    //Product structure that defines the type of data structure
    typedef struct
    {
        int code;
        char description [20];
        char MeasureUnit [5];
        float price;
        type discriminant;
        union
        {
            char origin [20];
            char destination [20];
            int telephone;
        } impoExpo;
    } Product;

//procedure loadProduct
void loadProduct (Product *p)
{
    printf("\nEnter the code:");
    scanf("%d",&p->code);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter the description:");
    scanf("%s",p->description);
    printf("Indicate the unit of measure:");
    scanf("%s",p->MeasureUnit);
    printf("Enter the price:");
    scanf("%f",&p->price);
    int i;
    printf("\nInsert 1 if imported");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if(i == 1)
    {
        p->discriminant = IMPORTED;
    }
    else
    {
        p->discriminant = LOCAL;
    }
    if(p->discriminant == IMPORTED)
    {
        printf("\nEnter source: ");
        gets(p->impoExpo.origin);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nEnter the phone");
        scanf("%d", &p->impoExpo.telephone);
    }
}

void copy (Product * const destination, const Product * const origin)
{
    destination->code = origin->code;
    (*destination->description) = (*origin->description);
    (*destination->MeasureUnit) = (*origin->MeasureUnit);
    destination->price = origin->price;
    destination->discriminant = origin->discriminant;

    if(destination->discriminant == IMPORTED)
        (*destination->impoExpo.origin) = (*origin->impoExpo.origin);
    else
        destination->impoExpo.telephone = origin->impoExpo.telephone;
}
```